# How do I debug Azure Spatial Anchors with Unity on an Android device?

Tags: unity, c#, android, cloud-computing

I've been building an AR app that's already been a pain to debug, because instant preview refuses to work over wifi and usb debugging causes the phone camera to not display on the phone itself. Now I'm at the point where I can integrate Azure Spatial Anchors and I cannot seem to be able to be able to play in the editor. I receive the message:

DllNotFoundException: azurespatialanchorsndk
Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession..ctor () (at Assets/AzureSpatialAnchorsPlugin/Plugins/Common/AzureSpatialAnchorsBridge.cs:6864)
SpatialAnchors.GetCloudManager () (at Assets/Scripts/SpatialAnchors.cs:60)
tester.Start () (at Assets/tester.cs:18)

Answer (score 1):

That error message you have looks like one I saw last week, but I was not using the ARCore Instant Preview. But maybe this is still relevant?

It sounds like your situation is that the Azure Spatial Anchors NuGet package did not install into the Visual Studio solution like it was supposed to. 
It's possible this bug occurred because your Azure Spatial Anchor packages were added after the Visual Studio solution was already built out?

The workaround I found was to manually install the NuGet package. 
You can resolve the issue by manually installing it through the [NuGet website](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.WinCPP/).

You may also use Visual Studio's Package Manager Console to do it like this:

`Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.WinCPP -Version 1.1.1`

[image]

Comment: This is the error I get when I attempt the install via VS console: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.WinCPP.Redist 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more 
information, contact the package author.